# Why my "0" on AbsoluteLayout it is not at the start?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, absolutelayout

I am trying to put a Image at the start of the X but it is not working. What should I do? I want to use absoluteLayout with proporcions to be able to have a good looking in differents screens. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WW.Views.MainPage" 
             Padding="0"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainGreen}"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="BWLogo.png"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,.5,.5"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
        <Image Source="person2.png"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,.6,.5,.5"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the screen that I am getting from the code:
[person2.png it´s not align correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkw00.png)

Comment: what is it supposed to look like?  What specifically is wrong?

Comment: @Jason the person2 png should be at the very start of the screen at the X axis, as the LayoutBounds of it is “0,.6,.5,.5”, but it is not.

Comment: I could not find which one is person2 png. Could you use another background color to confirm? We still need more details.